# Empty page with number at the end of chapter

Tags: page-numbering

My thesis document is having an empty page at the end of the chapter. The page is numbered too. Any ideas what could have caused this ?

Comment: Is the empty page an even numbered one (left)? You probably used a `book` class. Look up the options `twoside` and `oneside`. Or privide an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the page number is even, then an empty page is often created by `\cleardoublepage` either explicitly or via `\chapter` or similar commands that call `\cleardoublepage` to get on an odd-numbered page.

There are other reasons for empty pages, but then try to create a minimal working example (MWE) that shows the problem.

Comment: The last subsection of the chapter ends at an odd numbered page.

Comment: Then the following empty page is even numbered. What follows after that chapter? Another chapter, index or similar stuff?

Comment: Yes the empty page is even numbered. Next Chapter starts at the next page. I have not used '\cleardoublepage' explicitly.

Comment: Then `\cleardoublepage` is called by this next `\chapter` command.

Answer (score 0):

Load

```
\usepackage{emptypage}
```

This suppresses page numbers, headers and footers on empty pages --> see [documentation](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/emptypage/emptypage.pdf)